# How do I keep two article tables synced, but keep stock separate

Tags: mysql, database, database-replication

This is probably a more conceptual problem, but I couldn't find an easy solution.

Scenario: Two shops (say 'M' and 'S']. M is the master and determines the articles in the databases. Each maintains an independent stock. I have M's article table replicating to S, and I separated stock into a separate table with a common reference.

Now when new articles are added in M, they arrive at S too, but they won't have an entry in S's stock table. Similar problem with delete articles. Possible solutions:

- Do I create an entry in S's stock table each time a request is made
  for a new (not-test-existing) article?
- Do I have to scan regularly to check for missing stock entries.

Isn't there a more elegant way to solve this?

NOTE: To clarify, let me explain another way:

M already replicates the 'articles' table to S (using MySQL's replication mechanism.
This works fine.

The problem is that M and S have 'stock' tables which are local to each M and S. What is the normal procedure when, for example, a new product is added (in M) to the 'articles' table, and transferred to S. Now there is new entry which doesn't have a corresponding entry in S's stock table.

I'm guessing this is not an unusual situation - what would be the normal procedure to solve this?

Comment: Who is B in problem #1?

Comment: What B :) Sorry about the typo. I first thought I would use A and B, then while typing, used M and S, which I thought would be more descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

Unless of course if you have *two* databases located on *two* different DB servers, why don't you simply create a table `articles` and a table `stock` referencing it. You could add the *shop* (ideally the `shop_id`) as an extra column of that latter. Something like that:

```
CREATE TABLE articles(id int primary key not null,
                      name char(20) not null);

CREATE TABLE stock(article_id int not null,
                   shop ENUM('M', 'S') not null,
                   qty int not null,
                  FOREIGN KEY(article_id) REFERENCES articles(id),
                  UNIQUE(article_id, shop));
```

Please see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e6eca/5 for a live example.

If you really need to restrict creation of items on table `articles` to *shop M* that could be achieved by creating different users for your DB (*user_m*, *user_s*) and using `REVOKE` and/or `GRANT` to setup the various access rights.

---

**EDIT:** If the two servers are on distant sites, you would probably be able to use [MySQL replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html) capabilities to keep one or many tables in sync between the two sites. This will require a network access between the two sites. As of myself, for obvious reasons, I would consider using a secure tunnel between the two sites. Finally you still probably have to set-up permissions at DB-level to only allow insert from one site and not the other.

As a "poor's man" solution, you finally have the possibility to backup on regular basis the required tables from one server to update the tables on the second server. A combination of mysqldump + cronjob would be good starting point.

As of myself, I would though push to *MySQL replication*. The setup is probably more complex. But this will perform better, scale better and have lower latency.

Comment: Thanks, Sylvain. I'm afraid that is not possible: both shops run their own local database, as we can't really rely on the communication between them. I only use replication to get the info in S updated as soon as possible.

Comment: @jcoppens By re-reading your question, I noticed than when you talking about replication you probably talking about "custom-made replication". But MySQL has its own replication capabilities that might be an interesting option in your very specific case.

Comment: I've added a note to the original post. I already replicate, with MySQL's mechanism, for the main articles table.

Comment: @jcoppens Is there a reason preventing the stock table or table<b>s</b> to be shared across replication too?

Comment: Yes, each stock table is local, as products are not shared across locations. Only the product info (price/tech data/etc) is identical which is the main 'article' table.

Comment: For lack of a better solution, I split stock from the article database, and (try) to keep the article tables synced by replication.